# Moving files that contain who's name that contains what work, SOW, to a target subdirectory

Tags: powershell, batch-file, for-loop, move

So I want to move all files that contain the word 'SOW' in all sub directories of a directory to a sub directory in each sub directory. Example: If in sub2 there is a file named firstsow.txt, I want to move it to sub 2/SOW. I managed to do this with a the command "move *SOW* SOW". This works fine, but when I tried to run it recursively, not sure if that is the right term, for all sub directories (sub 1, sub 2 ect..), by running the command:

```html
for /r %a in (example/*) do call sow.bat
```

Here is the sow.bat file I called:

```html
move *SOW* SOW
```

I get a message that says "cannot move multiple files to a single file". What does this message mean my script is trying to do?

Comment: It's been a while since I did any batch programming, but I think that error means that there isn't a DIRECTORY named SOW, so it's assuming you are moving to a FILE named SOW.  It's smart enough not to allow you to try that, since you'd lose everything except one of the files you were trying to move.

Comment: all of the sub directories also contain a sub dir named SOW, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PowerShell was tagged for this:

```
$path = "c:\temp"
$toMatch = "SOW"

$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Filter "*$toMatch*" | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)} 
$files | ForEach-Object{
    # Found a file with $toMatch in the title 
    If(!(Test-Path "$($_.DirectoryName)\$toMatch")){[void](New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $toMatch -Path $_.DirectoryName)}
    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination "$($_.DirectoryName)\$toMatch"
}
```

Look for all files with `$toMatch` in there title and collect them in `$files`. For each of those files see if there is a folder in the same directory with the name `$toMatch`. If not create the folder. Then move that file into the directory.

Test with a small number of files and it seemed to work.

Comment: I apologise, I thought powershell was another name for the comand line. I have just learned that the computer I am working on has powershell installed, but I have no idea how to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
for /R %a in (example\*SOW*) do move "%a" "%~Pa\SOW"
```

Execute previous command in the command-line. If you want to include it in a Batch file, double the percent-signs.

Comment: I ran this command, but it did not work. It also did not return any erro  messages

Comment: Insert and `echo` command before the `move` so we may see the names of the processed files...

Comment: i inserted the 'echo' comand 'for /R %a in (example\*SOW*) do echo move "%a" "%~Pa\SOW" ' when i ran this command nothing happend. Am i missing something fundemental here?

Comment: In the explanation of your problem you said that "running the command: `for /r %a in (example/*) do call sow.bat` ... I get a message that says 'cannot move multiple files to a single file'". My solution uses _your_ `for` command and just add the `move "%a" "%~Pa\SOW"` part! Please, check what is the difference of both `for` commands. For example, in your previous comment you missed a backslash in `in (example*SOW*) do` part...

Comment: when i used your method the moved files were renamed "SOW" and they were no longer identified as Adobe files.